# Runaway Argument. !File ended while scanning use of \next

Tags: latex, beamer

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Implementation Strategy}
        These are the scripts to create master and slave databases in both servers.
            \begin{verbatim}
                This is the SQL Server Script:
                    CREATE DATABASE master
                    go
                    USE master
                    go
                    CREATE TABLE tabel1(
                    id int identity not null primary key,
                    name varchar(128) not null)
                    INSERT INTO tab1 (name) VALUES ('Test 1')
                    INSERT INTO tab1 (name) VALUES ('Test 2')
                This is the PostgreSQL Script
                    CREATE DATABASE slave OWNER sqlrepl;
                    \connect slave
                    CREATE TABLE tabel1(id int not null primary key, name varchar(128) not null);
                    ALTER TABLE tabe11 OWNER TO sqlrepl;
            \end{verbatim}
    \end{frame}
```

I am finding the error of winetd software that File is ended and use of \next.
I ended lost of time finding this.

Comment: No problem here. You must be doing something else that's not included in your code.

Comment: This was a problem in an old beamer version and fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/0c387deb21263aff6bc4864618e3cb74dcf32357

Answer (score 0):

See
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225581/beamer-file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-next,

```
  \end{frame}
```

may not be indented!

Answer (score -1):

Other things can lead to this.

For example, if you do not use a capital "C" when commenting a step in an algorithm -- i.e., when you use \comment{...} instead of \Comment{...}.